# Creating an interactive seating map in Android Studio using either a custom layout or webview

Tags: android, html, android-studio, layout, android-webview

So I'm on my first android project and I'm implementing a native app. One of the components is to book a seat on a seating map.

General specifications:
Handle venues that have different seating layouts and amount of seats, over 200
The seats can have different sizes and shapes, i.e.  large round VIP seats and standard square seats. Imagine small round stadium with a lot of custom seating and different orientation, with a stage in the middle. (I have an image but can't post because I don't have enough reputation)

What I have tried so far:
Created custom seat class with size, seat number, orientation and seat type
Used a StaggeredGridLayout and a view-adapter to load each of these objects dynamically from a DB onto this layout.

My concerns: No matter how much I was worked on it, it never came out the way I wanted. Basically, I think this is better for grid maps with one sized objects like bus seats placed in the distance between each other and doesn't have a huge irrelevant object in the middle like a stage.

I was thinking about changing directions completely after doing some research: Using webview? Each venue would be a web page, that would be linked from the venue object from the DB. Then in that web page, I could make this sort of venue a lot easier because I could just place out this layout manually and style with different div elements or make an interactive javascript map, attach a button and make a call using Jquery/Javascript to my native android app.

What are your opinions, is this a feasible solution?

Comment: you can see the updated answer. Let me know if it helps

Answer (score 1):

To be honest, an interactive seat map development was the most challenging task I have ever had in my development life. But some how I have done it for an asymmetric seat plan.

This type of work can be achieved in following two ways.

**1. Using GPU rendering -** Much easier process as almost every device has GPU by default. It detects the interaction point and check it's RGB value to detect the right path has been interacted and return this through client interface (with some drawbacks). e.g: Webview interacting Js interface in android and others.

**2. Using CPU based drawing -** Draw each and every path on the canvas and repeatedly it need to check the touched/interacted point is inside the paths or not. It will use  **more** the CPU if paths are **more** complex to render/draw on the canvas for every single interaction. (hug CPU usage and some other constraints)

I am tired of searching some `library` in android which is very useful like **[Macaw](https://github.com/exyte/Macaw)** in iOS development. This library handles the interactive path inside a svg file and help to interact with the client side.

Anyways for me, neither of the two options are not feasible though. I will go with importing/downloading `.svg` file to your android application and make it interaction using `JavascriptInterface` in your app. Unfortunately, this is **less worse** solution that I have found out so far.

**UPDATE:**

Here is my approach to make it workable. See my [medium](https://medium.com/@scode43/interactive-svg-image-in-android-app-using-kotlin-and-javascript-6715c16397bb) blog post. Hope it will help you.